# Passing an STL queue as parameter to another function in C++

Tags: c++, function, data-structures, stl, fifo

I am having some issues passing a queue as a parameter to a function in C++
I have an STL queue defined `queue<int> example[100];`

I have a function defined `void calculateSum(queue<int> &example, int size){}`

I am trying to pass the queue to this function by writing `calculateSum(example, 100)` but I keep getting an error saying `[cquery] no matching function for call to 'minimumDistance'`

What should I do? Any feedback would be helpful

Comment: What is `calculateSum` actually supposed to do, then? If it's supposed to act on an array of `queue`s, you'll need to change its signature to accept one instead of taking a single `queue` and a size parameter.

Comment: Why do you suspect the problem is the line `calculateSum(example, 100)` when the error message names `minimumDistance` as the problem? (That line does appear to have an error, but not the one you quoted.)

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration `queue<int> example[100];` makes an array of 100 queues.

What you probably want is just `queue<int> example;` and then let it grow as you add elements.

Comment: i actually want an array of 100 queues

Comment: You may want to try vector<queue<int>> instead. I find vectors much easier to work with than arrays when dealing with complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

`queue<int> example[100];` will create an array (named `example`) of queues. Your function, `void calculateSum(queue<int> &example, int size)`,  accepts a reference to a *single* queue of ints (not an array of queues).

Assuming you do in fact want an array of queues, and you do want that function to accept a reference only to a single queue, you must choose one of the queues from your array to pass into it. For example, you could do `calculateSum(example[0], 123);` to pass in the first queue in your array.